# Using Multiple Annotations in Django

Tags: django

Here is my data base:

```
class User(models.Model):
   Name = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)

class Salary(models.Model):
   value = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
   name = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='salarys', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Expense(models.Model):
   value = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
   name = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='expenses', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

I want to add all the salary and expenses of a user. 

queryset = User.objects.annotate(total_salary=Sum('salarys__value', distinct=True) ,total_expense=Sum('expenses__value', distinct=True))
```

Here is my data:

```
User table
id=1; name= ram

Salary table
id =1; value = 12000
id = 2; value = 8000

Expense table
id =1; value=5000
id=2; value = 3000
```

> **expected output :**  total_Salary = 20000; total_expense=8000 output
>
> **obtained :** total_salary= 40000; total_expense = 16000

Every output is multiplied the number of times the data in another table. Can anyone help me through this

Answer (score 1):

looks like it is not possible if you are trying to combine like aggregates. Only works for Count with distinct. For closure, please refer to docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations

Since annotate returns a queryset instead of a dict(in case of aggregate), you can try chaining multiple like `values().annotate("field1").annotate("field2")`. Worked for me, though please check sql from your queryset to debug in case you cannot run your query as desired.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this ?

```
queryset = User.objects.all().annotate(total_salary=Sum('salarys__value') ,total_expense=Sum('expenses__value'))
```

Comment: i am getting no change in output

Comment: in the salary table,you are supposed to have a foreign key to user,why havent you specified it?

Comment: there is a foreign key in both tables

Comment: edit your question .you have mentioned like salary table: id=. salary =  ...there is no field called salry in salary table

Comment: actually thats value. i just wanted to remove confusion using value twice